# c# binary serialization to file line by line or how to seperate

Tags: c#, .net, json, file, serialization

I have a collection of objects at runtime, which is already serializable, I need to persist the state of the object to a file. I did a quick coding using BinaryFormatter and saved A serialized object to a file.

I was thinking that I can save object per line. but when i open the file in a notepad, it was longer than a line. It wasnt scrolling. How can i store an binary serialized object per line?

I am aware that i can use a separator after each object so while reading them back to the application, i can know the end of the object. Well, according to information theory, this increases the size of the data(Sipser book).

What s the best algorithm to come up with a separator that woudldnt break the information?

Instead of binary serialization? Do you think JSon format is more feasible? can i store the entity in a json format, line by line?

Also, serialization/deserialization introduces overhead, hits the performance. Would Json be faster?

ideas?

Thanks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serialization functions like a FIFO queue, you dont have to read parts of the file because the formatter does it for you you just have to know the order you pushed objects inside.

```
public class Test
    {

        public void testSerialize()
        {
            TestObj obj = new TestObj();
            obj.str = "Some String";
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
            formatter.Serialize(stream, 1);
            formatter.Serialize(stream, DateTime.Now);
            stream.Close();
        }

        public void TestDeserialize()
        {
            Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            TestObj obj = (TestObj)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            int obj2 = (int)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            DateTime dt = (DateTime)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    class TestObj
    {
        public string str = "1";
        int i = 2;
    }
```

Comment: interesting. i should try that.

Comment: ok question: how do you know how many objects are in the file? how do u plan to populate all of them?

Comment: actually you cant know how many, because objects of different type can be inside, however if you know that only objects of type X are inside you can deserialize in a loop putting objects in an list and catch a Serialization exception when passing end of stream, which means you have finished.. but that is error prone, since you must rely on the exception message "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed"

Comment: @user177883 Either make sure that the first object you serialise is a header (e.g. `int`) containing the number of objects, or check for EOF after reading each object.

Comment: yes well tought +1, you could put the count in the first position :)

Comment: @Marino, that s what i am trying now. @Kragen, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

> Serialization/deserialization introduces overhead, would Json be faster?

JSON is still a form of serialisation, and no it probably wouldn't be faster than binary serialisation - binary serialisation is intended to be compact and quick, wheras JSON serialisation puts more emphasis on readability and so many be slower as is very likely to be less compact.

You could serialise each object individually and emit some separator between each object (e.g. a newline character), but I don't know what separator you could use that is guarenteed to not appear in the serialised data (what happens if you serialise a string containing a newline character?).

If you use a separator that the .Net serialisation framework emits then obviously you will make it difficult (if not impossible) to correctly determine where the breaks between objects are leading to deserialisation failures.

Why exactly do you want to put each object on its own line?

Comment: so i can read the objects line by line, and i woudlnt need a seperator.

Comment: @user177883 Why not just serialise an array of objects instead?

Comment: that might work. good idea. Should i store all the objects in a list and then serialize the list to the file?

Comment: @user177883 Thats what I'd probably do, or if you want to aovid deserialising the entire list at once then do what Marino suggests.

Comment: Marino creates 3 objects and read 3 objects. At runtime, i dont know how many object i have.

Comment: @user177883 You could first serialise a header object (for example and `int`) to the file which contains the count of objects saved - when reading simply ensure that you first pop / deserialise the `int` off the stack, and then you will know how many objects to deserialise.  You could also check to see if you have reached the end of the file whenever you finish deserialising (assuming you don't serialise any extra data at the end of the file).

Answer (score 1):

Binary serialization saves the data to arbitrary bytes; these bytes can include newline characters.

You're asking to use newlines as separators.   Newlines are no different from other separators; they will also increase the size of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a ArrayList and add the objects to it and then serialize it ;)

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(1);
list.Add("Hello World");
list.Add(DateTime.Now);

BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

FileStream fsout = new FileStream("file.dat", FileMode.Create);
bf.Serialize(fsout, list);
fsout.Close();

FileStream fsin = new FileStream("file.dat", FileMode.Open);
ArrayList list2 = (ArrayList)bf.Deserialize(fsin);

fsin.Close();

foreach (object o in list2)
   Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());
```